# How do I make my code more compact and elegant?

Tags: python, function

I have a piece of code as a prototype of what I want to do. I am making a GUI and a lot of the stuff I write is the same but with different variable names (e.g., widgets are almost the same). So I was thinking if there is a way to shorten the code:

Prototype:

```
frame_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
frame_widget.setLayout(self.button_frame)
self.centralframe.addWidget(frame_widget)

timer_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
timer_widget.setLayout(self.timer_frame)
self.centralframe.addWidget(timer_widget)
```

Is it possible to make a function or something else to avoid the code repetition?

Answer (score 2):

For example,

```
def add_widget(frame, layout):
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(layout)
    frame.addWidget(widget)

# usage
add_widget(self.centralframe, self.button_frame)
add_widget(self.centralframe, self.timer_widget)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that really changes between the two code blocks is the frame. You could put all the frames you need in a list, and then iterate over it:

```py
frames = [self.button_frame, self.timer_frame] # and any other frame you have...
for frame in frames:
    frame_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    frame_widget.setLayout(frame)
    self.centralframe.addWidget(frame_widget)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a huge improvement, but you could just make an anonymous `tuple` of the things to wrap in widgets and add, then loop over it:

```
for elem in (self.button_frame, self.timer_frame):
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(elem)
    self.centralframe.addWidget(widget)
```

It's more useful if you're talking about many such `elem`s, not just two.

This assumes you don't rely on the existence of `timer_widget` or `frame_widget` later on; if you do, you'd have to modify it to have a `widget_dict` of some sort, and have the loop run over pairs of `str` names and UI elements, so you could assign to the `dict` by name.

Comment: Thanks! I get the concept now

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method to the class that creates a widget for a given frame:

```
def addWidget(self,frame):
    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    widget.setLayout(frame)
    self.centralframe.addWidget(widget)
    return widget
```

You could then use it like this:

```
 frame_widget = self.addWidget(self.button_frame)
 timer_widget = self.addWidget(self.timer_frame)
```